# I have issue in Incremental Content Deployment in SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-server, content-deployment

I have an issue in Incremental Content Deployment from Staging to Production in SharePoint 2007, the job was running successfully, suddenly got the below error, so please help me to fix the issue.

> ContentDeploymentJob.UpdateLastStatus using status='Failure'
>
> Content deployment job 'Remote import job for job with sourceID = "" failed. The exception thrown was 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException':'Could not find Feature XXXX.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have a feature on your source site which is not available on the target site.

You need to disbale the feature at source site or You have to install it at target. Other wise this will broke.

Check these blogs for more information, how to find missing feature.

http://gavinmckay.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/sharepoint-2010-content-deployment-system-nullreferenceexception-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object/

http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2008/04/12/moss-common-issue-content-deployment-fails-with-failed-to-compare-two-elements-in-the-array.aspx

Comment: Hi Waqas, Thanks for your reply and more over I can't download the following tools WssAnalyzeFeatures and WssRemoveFeatureFromSite from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/. Can you help me in that.

Comment: those are gone by now, as MSFT mentioned that library reitred. Do you know which feature is mentioned in error. also try this codeplex solution...they have support for 2007 http://spfeatureadministration.codeplex.com/

Comment: Hi Waqas, Thank you so much for your suggestion, I will try this first.